# How can I convert the recorded voice into noise using any algorithm in matlab?

Tags: matlab, noise

I'm trying to convert my recorded voice into noise, so that if someone plays the converted recording, it sounds to him like a noise. Then if I perform the reverse operation on the converted recording, i.e. noise, I should get the original voice back.

Here's my code for making the recorded voice into noise:

```
c = wavread('haseeb');
a = (c-min(c)) / (max(c)-min(c)); % normalization to bring the voice values in the range [0,1]

for i=1:length(a)
    % speading the values into the range[-1,1]

    if ((a(i,1)>=0) && (a(i,1)<=0.2))
        b(i,1) = a(i,1)-1;

    elseif ((a(i,1)>0.2) && (a(i,1)<=0.4))
        b(i,1) =a(i,1)+0.6;

    elseif ((a(i,1)>0.4) && (a(i,1)<=0.6))
        b(i,1) = a(i,1)-0.5;

    elseif((a(i,1)>0.6) && (a(i,1)<=0.8))
        b(i,1) = a(i,1)-1.2;

    elseif((a(i,1)>0.8)&&(a(i,1)<=1))
        b(i,1)=a(i,1)-0.4;

    else
    end
end
```

This code is working to some extent. The recorded voice is converted into noise but you can hear the original voice in the background, and if you play the noise slowed down, you can hear the voice. I would like to modify the code, so that it will completely become the noise and no one can hear the voice, and when I apply the reverse process, I'll get the original voice back.

Comment: i don't want to use any linear noises, e.g. awgn or salt&pepper.. i've to convert the voice into noise using some programming, so that the recorded voice should appear like noise to someone else, but when i apply the reverse process, i should get the original voice back.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use random orthonormal transformation matrix.
The idea is as follows:
1. First you generate a random square matrix of size `N`. Note that `N` is a window size and not the length of the signal.
2. Next, by using `svd` you construct a random orthonormal transformation.
3. Divide your signal into segments of length `N` and multiply each segment with the transformation.
4. To reconstruct the signal, simply multiply each segment with the transpose.
This is probably not the most efficient way to do as you wish but it should work.

Here is an example of such process using one of MATLAB built-in audio files:

```
load handel.mat
N = 256;
Frames = floor(numel(y)/N);
RandTrans = randn(N);
[U,S,V] = svd(RandTrans);
RandTransOrtho = U*V';
x = zeros(size(y));
yrec = x;
for k=1:Frames
    x((k-1)*N + (1:N)) = RandTransOrtho*y((k-1)*N + (1:N));
    yrec((k-1)*N + (1:N)) = RandTransOrtho'*x((k-1)*N + (1:N));
end
```